# R generate random vectors from multivariate distributions

Tags: r, random, distribution

I want to generate random points of uniform density over the unit ball [-1,1]^d in R.

Are there any R packages which offer this functionality?

I am sure i can do this myself by extending this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87238/250498 to d dimensions.

But i want to know if there is any function or package in R that already does this.

It would be useful if there is a package which can generate standard multivariate distributions instead of me having to sample them myself using rejection sampling or other techniques.

Comment: Which "standard multivariate distributions" are you interested in?

Comment: @Dason Well i guess multivariate normal, t , uniform  are enough, those are the most used anyway.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/mvtnorm.pdf gives the normal and t.  I don't personally know of a package that gives uniform on a ball but it's probably out there.

Comment: Although that seems like something there should be a package for. If I can't find anything I might just implement that myself to save some headaches in the future.

Comment: Please clarify - do you need uniform oevr VOLUME of the ball, or over SURFACE of the ball? And I don't think there is a package for that

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I actually need over the volume of the ball it is much more common i think and there should be a package/function for that.